# Read four bytes at a time from STDIN in ruby

Tags: ruby, hex, byte, stdin

I want to continously read four bytes at a time from STDIN and output that in hex.
I have tried using both read, readbyte, each_byte, but I cant seem to get it working.

```
cat file | ./processor.rb
0x...
0x...
...
```

where file is a binary file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Enumerable#each_slice`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_slice):

```
STDIN.each_byte.each_slice(4) { |b4|
  # Do something with `b4`. `b4` is an array that contains up to 4 bytes
}
```

or

```
STDIN.each_char.each_slice(4) { |c4|
  # Do something with `c4`. `c4` is an array that contains up to 4 characters
}
```